# Angular 2: many Async pipes vs one subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

What is better for performance and "angular way": have many async pipes in the view or one subscriber in the component with unsubscribe action onDestroy?

Example:

```js
@Component({
  template: `<div> {{ post.title }} {{ post.author.name }} {{ post.category.name }} </div>`
  ...
  })
class AppComponent {
  public post: Post;
  public postSubscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    postSubscription = someObservable.subscribe((post) => {
      this.post = post;
    })
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    postSubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

or

```js
@Component({
  template: `<div> {{ postTitle | async }} {{ postAuthorName | async }} {{ postCategoryName | async }} </div>`
  ...
  })
class AppComponent {
  public postTitle: Observable<string>;
  public postAuthorName: Observable<string>;
  public postCategoryName: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postTitle = someObservable.pluck('title');
    this.postAuthorName = someObservable.pluck('author', 'name');
    this.postCategoryName = someObservable.pluck('category', 'name');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `| async` pipe is more efficient because Angular gets notified about changes. With the first example the bindings are checked each change detection cycle.

Comment: But if I modify `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and in the subscribe block I use `changeDetector.markForCheck()`?

Comment: Then it's probably the same as using the async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. 
I often came across the decision of use multiple async pipes for the same observable, vs subscribing OnInit and unsubscribing onDestroy.